# onCreate() not getting called in the Database helper

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am having toruble with my database helper class. The Table is not getting created. 
I know there are several "Database not getting created" questions here and I have tried their solutions. 
I have checked that I call `mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase(), I have tried changing the table name and un-installing the reinstalling the app (after clearing the app data). It did not help. I am still getting the same messages in the error log

Here is the relevant bits of code. Let me know if you need to see any more of it.`

```
public class OfflineDBCache {

public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_JSON_STRING = "json_string";




private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
private static  SQLiteDatabase mDb;

/**
 * Database creation sql statement
 */
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
    "create table notes (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + "json_string integer not null);";


private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "data";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "offlineTable";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private final Context mCtx;

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS notes");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

/**
 * Constructor - takes the context to allow the database to be
 * opened/created
 * 
 * @param ctx the Context within which to work
 */
public OfflineDBCache(Context ctx) {
    this.mCtx = ctx;
}

/**
 * Open the notes database. If it cannot be opened, try to create a new
 * instance of the database. If it cannot be created, throw an exception to
 * signal the failure
 * 
 * @return this (self reference, allowing this to be chained in an
 *         initialization call)
 * @throws SQLException if the database could be neither opened or created
 */
public OfflineDBCache open() throws SQLException {
    mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
    mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close() {
    mDbHelper.close();
}
```

I know the table is not getting created because I get this in the Logcat:

```
04-05 00:07:25.602: E/SQLiteLog(8568): (1) no such table: offlineTable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating table ***notes***

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
    "create table notes (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + "json_string integer not null);"
```

So you should use ***notes*** insteadof ***offlineTable***

```
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "notes"; // Replaced offlineTable with notes
```

---

***Update for good practice***

As you are using constant for table name, you can modify your `DATABASE_CREATE` as below

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
    "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + "(_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + "json_string integer not null);";
```

same as for delete statement into onUpgare()

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
```

*As this is a good way and also you can easily change your table name, by changing value of `DATABASE_TABLE` only.*

Comment: it should also be noted that if you are going to create a final variable, you should use it when it is applicable. In this case the create statement should be "create table " + DATABASE_NAME + (_id integer primary key autoincrement, json_string integer not null);"

Comment: Thanks man. I copy pasted the class from one of my older apps and I was too tired to realise that I was doing something stupid.

Comment: @DrkStr no worries, I had a typo in mine where it should be DATABASE_TABLE instead of DATABASE_NAME. Just wanted to make note. Pankaj Kumar has fixed this in his code.